# Error in adding record to user with paypal ipn

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to add a record to user after he pays.

The code currently I'm using :

```
  $ordername = $_POST['item_name']; ,     $user = $_SESSION['username'];
    ,$payment_gross     = $_POST['mc_gross'];

  $insertOrder = $odb -> query("INSERT INTO orders (id, ordername, content, 
   status, list, username, date, price) VALUES(NULL, '$ordername', 0, 0, 0, 
   '$user', 0, , '$payment_gross')");
```

The problem is that it's not adding the record to the db.

Comment: do you get any error ?

Answer (score 1):

fix the issue in your query

you have passed the 8 parameters in a query and value parameter you are passed the 9 parameters "'$user', 0, , '$payment_gross'" just remove one "," after the "0,"

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of $odb ? if it's a PDO object, you should call

```
$odb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

So that the call to `query` will show what the error is.

From looking at your SQL though, it looks like you have 8 named parameters, but 9 in the list of values, although one of them is empty. So make sure you're passing the correct parameters.

**-- EDIT --**

Looking at your code above, it looks like there are extra commas in the top section.. I've tidied up your code and added error trapping.

It will write the result of your code to the file `results.txt`. After this is called, look in this file to see what happened.

```
$insertOrder='?';
$error='?';
try
{
    $ordername = $_POST['item_name'];
    $user = $_SESSION['username'];
    $payment_gross = $_POST['mc_gross'];

    $odb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $insertOrder = $odb -> query("INSERT INTO orders (`ordername`, `content`, `status`, `list`, `username`, `date`, `price`) VALUES ('$ordername', 0, 0, 0,'$user', 0,'$payment_gross')");
}
catch (Exception $ex)
{
    $error=$ex->getMessage();
}

file_put_contents('results.txt',"error: $error - sqlresult: $insertOrder");
```

Comment: didn't work in what way? did you try fixing the parameters? did it show any kind of error?

Comment: it didnt show sir , cuz its ipn page , the error will not show.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
$ordername = $_POST['item_name'];
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
$payment_gross     = $_POST['mc_gross'];

$insertOrder = $odb -> query("INSERT INTO orders (id, ordername, content, status, list, sername, date, price) 
 VALUES(NULL, '$ordername', 0, 0, 0, '$user', 0, '$payment_gross')");
```